# Insert data into logged in user document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a subdirectory that I want to add data to. this code solves that, but how do I say when a user is logged in then add it to it's subdirectory?

```
    app.post('/schedule', function(req, res){
  var b = new Account (req.body.b)
    b.activities.push(req.body.activities);
    b.save(function(){
      res.redirect('/');

    });
});
```

The code above simply adds post data to the activities document, But I want it add the data to logged in users. How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: Why not put it with your login code?

Comment: How should I implement that strategy? something like this --> app.post('/schedule',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res){
  var b = new Account (req.body.b)
    b.activities.push(req.body.activities);
    b.save(function(){
      res.redirect('/');

    });
});

Comment: I tried adding (var user = req.user;
  user.validated = true; )to the code but It gives me a validation error

Comment: I tried this-(but I am getting undefined is not a function err)->>app.post('/schedule', function(req, res){
  var activity = new activity ({title: req.body["activity.title"]});
  activity.user = req.user;
  activity.save(function(err){
    if(!err){
      res.redirect('/schedule');

    }
    else{
      res.redirect('/');
    }
   });
});